# Use form_for to update array attribute of object

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I've been seeing topics dancing around this issue, so maybe I've actually seen the answer and I've just been banging away at it too long that my brain can't recognize it.

In short, I *think* I need to mark my form data as dirty so that it will update the array field in the Freelancer object, but I seem to be missing something.

Important info: `programmingLanguages` below is an array field. In my migration I have:

```
t.text :programmingLanguages, array: true, default: []
```

So while I'm currently submitting only one string to said array, I want to be able to submit more than one eventually (and perform operations on the data when I need to down the line...)

I have a form:

```
<%= form_for(@freelancer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :programmingLanguages, "Programming languages (seperated by commas): "%>
    <%= f.text_field :programmingLanguages %>
    .
    .
    .
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "button"%>

<% end %>
```

Which submits fine and gives me a list of params I expect:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"long token", "freelancer"=>{"programmingLanguages"=>"Stuff for an array, more stuff for an array"...}
```

I then use those params to update attributes for my `@freelancer` object:

```
def create
    @freelancer = Freelancer.find(session[:user_id])
    if @freelancer.update_attributes(freelancer_params)
      redirect_to @freelancer
    else
      render root_path
    end
end
```

Because I'm using a multi-step form (hence the find by session), I'm updating the attributes in my create action vs. saving them because the object I'm working with already exists and is saved to the database. The issue is that when I use `update_attributes` I notice that the SQL commits are ignoring my array fields, such as programmingLanguages above, but does not disregard the other attributes in the params. In other words my integer field totalPrograms updates easily/correctly, but my 4 array fields get lost somewhere between the params and updating the @freelancer object.

Any help much appreciated!

**Update:**

Here are the strong params:

```
def freelancer_params
    params.require(:freelancer).permit(:programmingLanguages, :totalPrograms...)
end
```

One more note with this, I guess: I've tried indicating here that `:programmingLanguages` is an array (a la `:programmingLanguages => []` or `programmingLanguages: []`) and I get syntax errors (`syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>`). Which of course could just mean my syntax is off in setting theses as arrays in my strong params, but if that's the case then I can't find the dumb little error there either.

Comment: Can you post the `freelancer_params` method?

Comment: @Pavan Updated! Thanks for looking into all my questions lately.

Comment: Try putting `programmingLanguages: []` as last param in your `freelancer_params`.

Comment: @Pravan `Unpermitted parameter: programmingLanguages` shows up in the terminal (before the database commit), the array is not saved to the database, but the syntax error is no longer there.

Comment: Can you update with the latest params generated?

Comment: @Pravan actually there is no update...the latest params are identical to what's above.